# Significant p-value and anecdotical BF

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, p-value, statistical-power, bayes-factors

I'm conducting frequentist as well as Bayesian analyses. However, I have difficulties to interpret data.

Indeed, results showed significant p-value, but anecdotal BF10 (< 3). Likewise, there are non-significant p-value but anecdotal B01 (< 3).

I'm reading an article written by Wetzels et al. (2011) in link with this topic.

In both case, I don't conclude about acception of H0 or H1 ?

Generally, I have evidence when I conduct a test with BF10, but small evidence when test aims to assess evidence for H0. Are there reasons?

And is there a link with statistical power ? Indeed I have small sample, can we imagine that more participants would conduct to increase the evidence for H1 or H0 of BFs ?

Have a nice day

Cheers,

PM

Comment: Would you mind explaining which frequentist test and which Bayesian approack lead to exactly which p- or BF-values and how large your small sample is. This is very abstract and hard to guess what might be going on.

Comment: @Bernhard I used linear regressions based on ANOVA for frequentist and model comparison for BF with JZS prior (I use JASP) (I have one sample n=18 with two groups n=8 and =10). 

For example, I computed two linear regression for two differents outcome with the same predictor : sample n=8. For the first outcome : p-value <.001, BF10= 54 (so it is ok), but for the second outcome p-value = .108 and BF01 = .782

I compute similar linear regression with another group n=10. For the first outcome : p-value = 003, BF10= 17 (so it is ok), but for the second outcome p-value = .294 and BF01 = 1.43

Comment: Small sample sizes contain little evidence for either $H_0$ or $H_1$. For more about the relation of Bayes factors and sample size see https://www.nicebread.de/what-does-a-bayes-factor-feel-like/